# Бд не работает OpenServer

Tags: sql, база-данных, phpmyadmin, openserver

```
<?php
$login = filter_var(trim($_POST["login"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$name = filter_var(trim($_POST["name"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$pass = filter_var(trim($_POST["pass"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

if(mb_strlen($login) < 5 || mb_strlen($login) > 90){
    echo "Недопустимая длинна логина";
    exit();
}

if(mb_strlen($name) < 3 || mb_strlen($name) > 50){
    echo "Недопустимая длинна имени";
    exit();
}

if(mb_strlen($pass) < 4 || mb_strlen($pass) > 15){
    echo "Недопустимая длинна пароля";
    exit();
}

$mysql = new mysqli('localhost','root','','userbd');

$mysql->query("INSERT INTO `usera` (`login`, `pass`, `name`) VALUES('$login', '$pass', '$name')");

$mysql->close();
```

?>

ошибок нет никаких, но в базе данных ничего не создается[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: Уверен, ошибки есть, просто вы их не включили. См. ответы в ссылке выше

Comment: спасибо посмотрю

Comment: А вообще посмотрите тему подготовленных переменных. Их поддерживают такие драйвера для PHP как mysqli и pdo. В наше время это просто MUST HAVE против взлома и против косяков с синтаксисом